# How to create a videoview with a listview? Android

Tags: android, listview, android-videoview

I want to create a listview which has the path of my mp4 files and when i click it, it will play the video in my videoview which is located on the upper part of the listview. I've tried searching for it but i can't find any tutorial. The layout is like in the youtube app the video is playing on the upper part and underneath are the list of videos. I only seen a tutorial where you will use a SURFACEVIEW but it displays the video on the whole screen. Can anyone help me please? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant use videoview inside listview cause videoview extends surfaceview internally. Surfaceview cannot be scrolled reason [refere this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714989/surfaceview-in-listview-scrolling-issue)

**2 approaches i can suggest**

1) Use textureview instead of videoview

2) Hide the surfaceview when you scroll Like replace videoview with the imageview (showing thumbnail) when you scroll.

Comment: is there any tutorial i can use for guide?

Answer (score 1):

SurfaceView is a View and can be resized in any parent ViewGroup like other Views.It does not have to be fullscreen. Please consider using it in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achive something like these [Dragable video with list](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel)

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for this and its good. But i wanted to achieve something simple like the video is playing on the upper part of the screen while there is a listview under it where you can choose to play next

Comment: Could you please add a demo image for what you needed .